# PySpark: How to explode list into multiple columns with sequential naming?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have the following PySpark DF:

```
+--------+--------------------+--------------------+
|      id|           resoFacts|             heating|
+--------+--------------------+--------------------+
|90179090|[, [No Handicap A...|[Central Heat, Fo...|
+--------+--------------------+--------------------+
```

created by the following:

```
(data_filt
     .where(col('id') == '90179090')
     .withColumn('heating', col("resoFacts").getField('heating')))
```

I want to create a DF that expands the list in `heating` into sequentially named columns, as so:

```
+--------------+------------+----------+----------+---------+
|  id          |heating_1   |heating_2 | heating_3|heating_4|
+--------------+------------+----------+----------+---------+
|  90179090    |Central Heat|Forced Air|      Gas |Heat Pump|
+--------------+------------+----------+----------+---------+
```

My furthest attempt has generated the following DF:

```
+---+------------+----------+----+---------+
|pos|Central Heat|Forced Air| Gas|Heat Pump|
+---+------------+----------+----+---------+
|  1|        null|Forced Air|null|     null|
|  3|        null|      null| Gas|     null|
|  2|        null|      null|null|Heat Pump|
|  0|Central Heat|      null|null|     null|
+---+------------+----------+----+---------+
```

with this code:

```
(data_filt
     .where(col('id') == '90179090')
     .withColumn('heating', col("resoFacts").getField('heating'))
     .select("heating", posexplode("heating"))
     .groupBy('pos').pivot('col').agg(first('col')))
```

I'm likely doing something wrong with the line beginning with `groupBy`. Does anyone have thoughts?

Comment: you always have 4 elements in the array ?

Answer (score 0):

If you only have 4 elements in the array, you can simply do that :

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

data_filt.select(
    "id",
    *(
        F.col("heating").getItem(i).alias(f"heating_{i+1}")
        for i in range(4)
    )
)
```

Increase the `range` if you have more elements.

Comment: (1) the number of elements is variable and (2) need to do this on millions of rows (so should also be performant)

Comment: @mmz it is performant, way more performant that using a group by as it is a simple `map`. How many elements max do you have ? do you know ?

Comment: max would be ~10 elements. fwiw, this would be across multiple other columns as well

Comment: @mmz Please add more details where my solution does not work so I can elaborate on it ... currently, I do not see any reason why you should not use this solution.

Comment: @mmz this is a performant solution. If you need to make the solution more dynamic, you can first find the max range for your dataset and then add it to above solution with something like `for i in range(max_len)`. Then array items for which `length < max_len` will have  `max_len - length` `null` values